# Problema con retorno de activity android

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo 3 actividades: A, B y C

De la A paso a la B, depende del botón que pulso en B, me muestra unos botones de opciones en C, cuando pulso una opción en C, retorno un valor a la actividad A. Hasta ahí todo correcto, lo que quiero hacer es cuando en C, pulse la tecla hacía atrás vuelva a la actividad B, pero como tengo puesto un finish(), para que el valor elegido en C regrese a A, nunca puedo quedarme en B para volver a elegir.

Código en A para llamar a B :

```
startActivityForResult(actividad_B,100)
```

Código en B para llamar a C :

```
intent = Intent(context,actividad_c::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

Código de C :

```
intent_retorno = Intent()
intent_retorno.putExtra("boton elegido",valor_del_boton)
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent_retorno)
finish()
```

Comment: Tu mismo lo has dicho, tienes el finish puesto en la activity B, si lo quitas, la activity permanecerá en el stack y al salir de C, volverás a B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca puedes regresar de C a B ya que cuando cambias de B a C usas `finish()` , que destruye la Activity B, por lo tanto al tratar de regresar, la Activity ya no existe.

Si deseas regresar de C a B puedes evitar el llamado de `finish()` al cargar C :

```
 intent = Intent(context,actividad_c::class.java)
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT)
 startActivity(intent)
// finish()
```

otra opción es que cuando regreses de C, realices un intent para volver a cargar B

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        //Carga Activity B.
        intent = Intent(context, actividad_b::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

        super.onBackPressed();            
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, más o menos lo solucioné haciendo esto una vez en A